# Taking LngLat from Map click event and drawing it onto a canvas layer for mapboxGL

Tags: javascript, canvas, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm using mapboxGL and I can't figure this out... Has anyone had any luck taking the lng/lat from a click event and then drawing that on a separate canvas layer.

Example below:

```
map.on('click', (e) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(e.lngLat.lat, e.lngLat.lng, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fill();

  map.addLayer({
    id: 'canvas-layer',
    type: 'raster',
    source: {
      type: 'canvas',
      canvas: canvas,
      coordinates: [
        map.getBounds().getNorthWest().toArray(),
        map.getBounds().getNorthEast().toArray(),
        map.getBounds().getSouthEast().toArray(),
        map.getBounds().getSouthWest().toArray(),
      ],
    },
  });
});
```

Coordinates for the canvas source seem correct but the lng/lat for the actual circle is way off and I can't figure out if I should be using the x/y coords instead or using map.project() or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With so little code I cannot understand the objective of creating a canvas and a layer each time you click a point in the map just to create a circle. First of all, Mapbox will raise an error the second time as you always use the same name for the layer. What I would do is to create the canvas statically in HTML just over the map

```
<canvas id="canvasID" width="682" height="400" style="overflow:hidden">Canvas not supported</canvas>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Then create the map and adjust the canvas to map's size.

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    zoom: mapConfig.NYC.zoom,
    minZoom: mapConfig.NYC.zoom,
    center: mapConfig.NYC.center,
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
});

map.setMaxBounds([map.getBounds().getSouthWest().toArray(), map.getBounds().getNorthEast().toArray()]);

let width = map.getCanvas().clientWidth;
let height = map.getCanvas().clientHeight;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

And then the layer and the source before the click event.

```
map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('canvas-source', {
        type: 'canvas',
        canvas: 'canvasID',
        coordinates: [
            map.getBounds().getNorthWest().toArray(),
            map.getBounds().getNorthEast().toArray(),
            map.getBounds().getSouthEast().toArray(),
            map.getBounds().getSouthWest().toArray(),
        ],
        animate: true
    });

    map.addLayer({
        id: 'canvas-layer',
        type: 'raster',
        source: 'canvas-source'
    });
...
});
```

Then is when I would add the event within the map on load, just to paint a circle, and instead of using e.lngLat, using basically the mouse pointer args, because now the canvas size and coords are equal to mapbox initial size and zoom view.

```
map.on('click', (e) => {
    color = "#ff0000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(e.point.x, e.point.y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

I have created a fiddle with the solution [how to add a custom canvas and draw circles on click](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/gvjt3c9f/4/)

And the result looks like this, every time you click a new circle will be rendered in the canvas layer.
[image]

NOTE: You'll have some limitations with this approach as limiting the bounds and panning of the map, and surely on zoom you'll need to recalculate the mouse click position within the bounds viewed.